# getting exception Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans' in spring

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am getting this exception below which mite be due to incorrect xsd that i am using please advise how to  overcome from this

below is the xsd that i am using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
        xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.4.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

and below are the jars that i am using

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Release12/lib/thirdparty/tibco-ems/4.2.0/crimson.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Release12/lib/thirdparty/tibco-ems/4.2.0/jaxp.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Release12/lib/thirdparty/tibco-ems/4.2.0/jcert.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Release12/lib/thirdparty/tibco-ems/4.2.0/jms.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Release12/lib/thirdparty/tibco-ems/4.2.0/jndi.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Release12/lib/thirdparty/tibco-ems/4.2.0/jnet.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Release12/lib/thirdparty/tibco-ems/4.2.0/jsse.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Release12/lib/thirdparty/tibco-ems/4.2.0/jta-spec1_0_1.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Release12/lib/thirdparty/tibco-ems/4.2.0/tibcrypt.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Release12/lib/thirdparty/tibco-ems/4.2.0/tibjms.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Release12/lib/thirdparty/tibco-ems/4.2.0/tibjmsadmin.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Release12/lib/thirdparty/tibco-ems/4.2.0/tibjmsapps.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Release12/lib/thirdparty/tibco-ems/4.2.0/tibrvj.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Release12/lib/thirdparty/tibco-ems/4.2.0/tibrvjms.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring-jms.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/commons-lang-2.6.jar/commons-lang-2.6.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/tibco/log4j-1.2.9.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/tibco/spring-context-2.0.4.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/org-apache-commons-logging.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-core-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-event-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-feed-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-file-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-ftp-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-groovy-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-http-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-httpinvoker-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-ip-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-jdbc-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-jms-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-jmx-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-mail-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-rmi-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-security-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-sftp-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-stream-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-test-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-twitter-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-ws-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-xml-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-xmpp-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/org.springframework.jms-3.1.0.M1.jar/org.springframework.jms-3.1.0.M1.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/xerces.jar/xerces.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/xercesImpl.jar/xercesImpl.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jre7"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring-2.5.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
```

the exception that i am getting is

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 11 in XML document from class path resource [jms-spring-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 116; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:369)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:313)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:142)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:158)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:184)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:112)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:79)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:100)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:313)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:91)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:75)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:65)
        at com.apress.prospringintegration.test.main(test.java:23)
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 116; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
```

folks please advise how to overcome from this, is this issue is related to classpath

Answer (score 0):

It seems your default namespace is beans. I guess you have beans:bean at line 11, just use it without the beans prefix (bean class="....")

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the advise but still not able to grasp could you please correct my above example that will help in understanding a better bit

Answer (score 0):

1. Use "versionless" XSD defintions for Spring Namespaces.
2. Try to use as last Spring jars version as possible.
3. First of all looks like you have a version mess there, from other side all those are so old, that they are already out of maintenance.
4. You should show your donwstream XML anyway. The Manespace definition isn't enough to determine that issue.
5. Try to clean your XML from tags and restore them one by one to catch the perpetrator.
6. From other side it might just an Eclipe issue, when switching on the Spring Nature for project should fix the problem.

Comment: I mean clean your XML config and leave only the Namespace definitions. Than restore your XML tags one by until your don't catch the same issue.